# Error: Cannot find module './lib/mediaType'" (after successful login)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I have implemented small application including user registration/login, using **Passport** and **Express** for routing and mongodb/node.js.

I am not using any optional login with Facebook or Google etc. code was already working 100%. Checking after few weeks something changed and after successful login, which was verified both by console.log and MongoDB window logs

I do get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/mediaType'"
```

The error is occurring in response to res.redirect line within the `app.post('/login)`. See relevant code below.

When I remark this line and just console.log there is no problem

Full error message:

```
successful login authentication

module.js:540
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/mediaType'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

    at loadModule (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\negotiator\index.js:114:16)

    at Negotiator.mediaTypes (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\negotiator\index.js:76:29)

    at Accepts.type.Accepts.types (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\accepts\index.js:105:33)

    at IncomingMessage.req.accepts (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\express\lib\request.js:134:23)

    at ServerResponse.res.format (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:627:11)

    at ServerResponse.redirect (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:888:8)

    at D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\app.js:113:6

    at D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:249:29

    at D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:51:48

    at D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:16:14

    at pass (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:297:14)

    at Authenticator.serializeUser (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:299:5)

    at SessionManager.logIn (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:14:8)

    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js
:50:33)

    at Strategy.strategy.success (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.j
s:248:13)

    at verified (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)

    at PBKDF2.ondone (D:\GitHub\js_exmpls\authentication\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\lib\authenticate.js:48:12))
```

I have installed media-type library and added following line to my app.js:

```
"var mediaType = require('media-type');"
```

The result is no change in error message. The error is occurring in response to res.redirect line, within the `app.post('/login)`. See relevant code below:
when I remark this line and just console.log there is no problem.

**Code:**

```
var http = require('http');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongodb=require('mongodb'); 

var express=require('express');

var csv = require('csv');

var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

var fs = require('fs');

var path=require('path');

var assert= require('assert');

var User= require("./models/user.js");

var passport= require('passport');

var mediaType = require('media-type');

var LocalStrategy= require('passport-local');

var passportLocalMongoose= require('passport-local-mongoose');

var mongoClient=require('mongoose');

var app = express();

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

.

.

 app.get('/login', function (req, res) {

 res.render('login' );

})
.

.


app.post("/login",function(req,res,err){

    if (err) {console.log(err); };//else not needed render is end

    passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){

       console.log("successful login authentication");

    res.redirect("./views/friends.ejs");

    });

    })
```

Comment: Can you add the whole error stack trace?

Comment: added full error stack message. thx

Comment: the problem comes from the module `negotiator` that is used by one of your modules. try running `npm uninstall negotiator` and then `npm install negotiator`

Comment: so fast - thx - i will try

Comment: one thing i changed is move to node version 8.9.1 maybe is related

Comment: to SunrisedM comment -  it worked!    but it is weared because the negotiator package was never included in my code- nor in package.json dependencies. .

Answer (score 3):

Just copying [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372085/error-cannot-find-module-lib-mediatype-after-successful-login#comment83731628_48372085) as an answer, since it worked for both the OP and me:

> he problem comes from the module negotiator that is used by one of your modules

```
npm uninstall negotiator
npm install negotiator
```